# Specifying random chance

Tags: java

Now , I will generate random numbers between 1 to 5. I assume there has probability or chance to gain on each number . *(please assume for example if you don't agree it)*

> 1 has 20%
>
> 2 has 20%
>
> 3 has 20%
>
> 4 has 20%
>
> 5 has 20%

I would like to increase or decrease chances of some numbers as I wish..

> 1 has 10%
>
> 2 has 10%
>
> 3 has 35%
>
> 4 has 40%
>
> 5 has 5%

If so , I can generate random numbers as I wish. Some were hard to get and some will gain frequently.
How can I achieve it by Java ? Please support me with some examples or some useful links or anything else.  I would really appreciated it. Please don't be suggest to describe some my efforted codes because I have no idea for this and I request some useful suggestions from you . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got percentages - so imagine you rolled a die with a value from 1-100. 1-10 => 1. 11-20 => 2. 31-55 => 3. 56-95 => 4. 96-100 => 5. Now think about how to code that.

Comment: Create a list with 10 ones, 10 twos, 35 threes, 40 fours and 5 fives. Shuffle the list. Pick the first element. Voilà!

Comment: @AskThakare as my described , `Some were hard to get and some will gain frequently.`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
double r = random.nextDouble();
if (r < 0.1) ret = 1
else if (r < 0.2) ret = 2
else if (r < 0.55) ret = 3
...
```

you get the idea, use the cumulative likelihood as threshold.

Answer (score 4):

First instantiate `java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();`. Do this exactly once.

From there, one approach is to use `double f = rand.nextDouble();` which gives you a number between (and including) 0 to (and not including) 1.

Then transform using a series of `if`s:

```
if (f < 0.1){
    return 1;
} else if (f < 0.1 + 0.1){
    return 2;
} else if (f < 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.35){
    return 3;
... /*can you see the pattern*/
```

It's not quite the fastest way, but is clear and will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way with the Random library.
But I think you can generate a Random number between 1 and 100.
And so, you can code that between:

1 and 10 you obtain 1,
11 and 20 you obtain 2,
21 and 55 you obtain 3,

and so on

Answer (score 0):

An alternative I can think about it is

```
int[] a = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5};

Random r = new Random();
return a[ r.nextInt(100) ];
```

Comment: Oh ! Do you mean I would need to specify hard code ?

Comment: ah, yes, Anony-Mousse and Bathsheba's solutions are good enough ... that's why I said **Alternative**